# How to make an object defined in a constructor visible to the rest of the class

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to access an object defined in a constructor from a method in the same class.

Is it possible for the other method to access the object, while still initialising it in the constructor?

```
class Number {
    public Number (int num1, int num2) {
        Calculator calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
        Calculator calc2 = new Calculator(num2);
    }

    public void displayNumber() {
        System.out.println(calc1.result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the declaration to the scope of the class? iow make it a field.

Comment: Save the object in a field instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Your only choice is to declare them outside the constructor, and initialize them in it:

```
class Number{

    Calculator calc1;
    Calculator calc2;

    public Number(int num1, int num2){

       calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
       calc2 = new Calculator(num2);

    }
    public void displayNumber(){

        System.out.println(calc1.result);
    }
}
```

Variables declared in the constructor, just as those declared in any method, are out of scope to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable in class level not locally:

```
    class Number{

            Calculator calc1;
Calculator calc2;

    public Number(int num1, int num2){

           calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
           calc2 = new Calculator(num2);

        }
        -----------other code--------------
        }
```

Comment: Not it's usefull to give exactly same answer as already given, but less well indented

Comment: I was slow in typing :(

Answer (score 0):

Save the value in a field:

```
class Number{

    final Calculator calc1;

    public Number(int num1, int num2){
        calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
        Calculator calc2 = new Calculator(num2);
    }
    public void displayNumber(){
            System.out.println(calc1.result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the local variable outside the scope.

```
// Here calc1 and calc2 are scoped only to the constructor
public Number(int num1, int num2){

    Calculator calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
    Calculator calc2 = new Calculator(num2);

}
```

If you want to access them outside declare an instance variable and do the instantiation in your constructor and then access it.

```
   Calculator calc1;
   Calculator calc2;
   public Number(int num1, int num2){
        calc1 = new Calculator(num1);
        calc2 = new Calculator(num2);
    }
   public void displayNumber(){
       System.out.println(calc1.result);
   }
```